# Regex lookahead in Python troubleshooting

Tags: python, regex

trying to get a regex lookahead that works to pull the IP address from each line of a dataset.
Sample data (pulling IP address at start):

```
13.112.8.80 - rau5026 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:09 -0700] "HEAD /ubiquitous/transparent HTTP/1.1" 200 16928  
159.253.153.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700] "POST /e-business HTTP/1.0" 504 19845  
136.195.158.6 - feeney9464 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:11 -0700] "HEAD /open-source/markets HTTP/2.0" 204 21149
```

My lookahead works great for those entries with a username (ex. rau5026 in the first line), but includes the first dash for those with no username (second entry, with a "-" as the username...
So for the first entry, it returns "13.112.8.80", but the second returns "159.253.153.40 -"

The regex I'm using is :

```
^.*(?=\s-\s)
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex rather than `split()` here? For example: `ip, rest = s.split(None, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex to match with IPv4 IP-adresses. Your regex is way too permissive.

```
(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

This will match with the following:

```
13.112.8.80
159.253.153.40
136.195.158.6
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
^[^ ]+
```

It translates to:

> Read everything from the start of each line that is not a space char.

It's a log file with a predictable and known format so simplicity is better. You don't need to verify that the start of each line is an IP address because it's guaranteed.

https://regex101.com/r/f5kJf6/1